# remove \\u{e2} characters from string

Tags: swift, string, swift3

I copied mobile number from contact . I got it like "8008708600\u{e2}" . I wish to remove  **\u{e2}** from string.  String is copied with exponent character which I dont want.

**Ex: "8008708600\u{e2}"** 
so desired output is **8008708600**

I used following code

```
let formattedString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " \\u{e2}”, with: "")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks so much!

Comment: There is a space before the string for replacement in `string.replacingOccurrences`.

Comment: So you did not get output using this.?

Comment: are the numbers have fixed length ?

Comment: You are using extra back slash in your string so it won't replace your string. so remove one back slash(\) from it and get the out put. Enjoy.

Comment: lock this .............. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668625/3325024 thank you

Answer (score 1):

I made a function for help:

```
public func formatContactsPhoneNumber(number: String) -> String {
    var buffer = ""
    for (i, char) in number.unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
        guard CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char) else {
            continue
        }
        buffer.append(number[i])
    }
    return buffer
}
```

It's work well for me.

Comment: this could be simplified to `String(number.unicodeCharacters.filter { CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains($0) })`, or, `string.replacingOccurrences(of: " [^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)`

Answer (score 0):

I have used following Code:

```
 var str = "8008708600\u{e2}"
 str = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{e2}", with: "")
 print(str)
```

Output:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
var number = self.yourTextField.text

self.yourTextField.text = ""
let onlyDigits: CharacterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
let greeting = number!
number = ""
for aa in 0..<greeting.count {
    let index = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: aa)

    let bb = String(describing: greeting[index])

    if bb.rangeOfCharacter(from: onlyDigits) == nil {
        number = "\(String(describing: number!))\(greeting[index])"
    }
}

self.yourTextField.text = number!
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [Tips on How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)