# how can I remove special character from phone number in swift?

Tags: swift, numbers, format

When I copy number phone from phone app I get results like this  `\u{e2}05xxxxxx49\u{e2}`

I need to remove this character `\u{e2}` from the left and right of the number
to get a result like this `05xxxxxx49`

```
var str = number
str = str!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{e2}", with: "")
print(str!)
```

Comment: Possible duplicated with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938468/remove-ue2-characters-from-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Here's what I did.

```
    var number = self.myTFForNumber.text
    
    self.myTFForNumber.text = ""
    let onlyDigits: CharacterSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
    let greeting = number!
    number = ""
    for aa in 0..<greeting.count
    {
        
        let index = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: aa)
        
        let bb = String(describing: greeting[index])
        
        if bb.rangeOfCharacter(from: onlyDigits) == nil {
            
            number = "\(String(describing: number!))\(greeting[index])"
            
        }
        
    }
    
    self.myTFForNumber.text = number!
```

Comment: You are making it too complicated. `String(number.unicodeCharacters.filter { CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains($0) })`, or `number.replacingOccurrences(of: " [^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)` would do the same.